# mPDF: How do I call a particular function everytime a page break occurs?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am writing some text into my pdf like this:

```
foreach($body as $html_body){
  $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="font-family: sakalbharati;"><p>'.$html_body.'</p></div>');
}
```

Now the thing is that I call a function everytime I create a new page like this:

```
function report_header($mpdf,$page){ //This should be repeated in every page
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1 style="text-align: center; color: rgb(50, 91, 205); font-size: 35px;">
    <u>REPORT HEADER</u></h1>');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="text-align:center";><table style="background-color:rgb(81, 205, 50); border: 2px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <img src="../logo.png" width="150" height="150">
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <img src="../image1.jpg" width="200" height="150">
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <img src="../image2.jpg" width="200" height="150">
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:center">
                    <div style="background-color:rgb(148, 76, 17); width:100%; padding:5px; color: white; font-weight: bold;">'.trim($_POST["date"]).'</div><br>
                    <div style="background-color:rgb(20, 104, 104); padding:5px; color: white; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">News clips</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table></div><br>');
    $mpdf->SetFooter("Page: ".$page);
    return $page;
}
$mpdf->AddPage();
$page+=1;
$page = report_header($mpdf,$page);
```

The function `report_header()` should run everytime a new page is created. Since, in this case the page break occurs automatically, how and when do I call my function, as I have no idea when the page break occurs?

Comment: "as I have no idea when the page break occurs"  the docs say "mPDF has limited scope to control when automatic page-breaks occur, and does not have ‘widows’ or ‘orphans’ protection." (see [Page breaks](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html#:~:text=mPDF%20has%20limited%20scope%20to%20control%20when%20automatic%20page%2Dbreaks%20occur%2C%20and%20does%20not%20have%20%E2%80%98widows%E2%80%99%20or%20%E2%80%98orphans%E2%80%99%20protection.))

Comment: How do I call the function `report_header()` after every successful page break?

Comment: I tink you need to reverse the order, and do a `report_header()`, and then some data which will fit on the rest of that page. When you decide the page is full, you can start with another `report_header()`.  Keeping track of how much space is left on a page is difficult (see the not on "mPDF has limited scope..." )